# Send only those emails that have attachments by way of a VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I've just started working on macros and have made a pretty decent progress so far.

However, I'm stuck in a place and can't find an answer to it.

I'm using a macro to send emails to specific recipients via outlook. I'm sending multiple excel & pdf attachments in each email.

The code works fantastic! I, nonetheless, need to add a condition wherein an email that doesn't have any EXCEL attachments isn't sent and the outlook create mail item for this specific case only closes automatically.

The rest of the macro should continue for other clients with the excel attachments.

Hoping for someone to help me on this. Following is the code that I'm currently using.

```
Sub SendEmailWithReview_R()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim X As Long

    Lastrow = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For X = 10 To Lastrow
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olmailitem)

        With OutMail
            .To = Cells(X, 4)
            .CC = Cells(X, 6)
            .Subject = Cells(X, 8)
            .Body = Cells(1, 8)

            strlocation = "C:\Users\HKhan\Desktop\Final Macro\" & Cells(X, 1) & "-OICR.xlsx"
            On Error Resume Next
            .Attachments.Add (strlocation)
            On Error Resume Next
            strlocation = "C:\Users\HKhan\Desktop\Final Macro\" & Cells(X, 1) & "-OICLR.xlsx"
            On Error Resume Next
            .Attachments.Add (strlocation)
            On Error Resume Next
            strlocation = "C:\Users\HKhan\Desktop\Final Macro\" & "OIC - Bank Details" & ".pdf"
            On Error Resume Next
            .Attachments.Add (strlocation)
            On Error Resume Next
            strlocation = "C:\Users\HKhan\Desktop\Final Macro\" & "OICL - Bank Details" & ".pdf"
            On Error Resume Next
            .Attachments.Add (strlocation)
            On Error Resume Next
            .Display
            'send
        End With  
    Next X
End Sub
```

Comment: Note: Never ever use `On Error Resume Next` without proper error handling. This line just hides errors but they still occur you just cannot see them. Code with this line is almost not possible to debug/fix.  Remove them completely or implement a error handling instead. • To your issue: Please show what you tried so far. This is no free code writing service.

Comment: Dear Peh, i did not take this to be a paid forum either!

Comment: With respect to your comments on error handler, I completely acknowledge  your advise. However, in my case, "on error resume next" is exactly what I want. I'm quite sure on how the code works. All i needed was an advise on how to add an if loop here such that any email without an excel attachment isn't shot.

Comment: Honestly, you can think about my advice, or resist learning something, I won't force you. But the fact that you use it 8 times in a row where 7 of them are completely useless makes it obvious that you don't know how `On Error Resume Next` works. Why? The first one already turns error reporting off and it never turns on again until `End Sub`. So using it multiple times without turning it back on is useless, you just cannot turn off a switch twice in a row before turning it on in between. The fact that you use it within a loop makes it even worse.

Answer (score 0):

So instead of waiting for errors or trying to suppress them better check if the file exists. Therefore you can use a function like this, which returns `true` if a file exists:

```
Public Function FileExists(FilePath As String) As Boolean
    Dim Path As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Path = Dir(FilePath)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Path <> vbNullString Then FileExists = True
End Function
```

For adding attachments I recommend to use an array for the file names, so you can easily loop through and attach the files if they exist. Everytime we add an attachment we increase the `AttachedFilesCount` too.

This way you don't use `On Error Resume Next` wrong and you don't run into debug issues because of that. So you have a clean solution.

```
With OutMail
    .To = Cells(X, 4)
    .CC = Cells(X, 6)
    .Subject = Cells(X, 8)
    .Body = Cells(1, 8)

    Dim FileLocations As Variant
    FileLocations = Array("C:\Users\HKhan\Desktop\Final Macro\" & Cells(X, 1) & "-OICR.xlsx", _
                          "C:\Users\HKhan\Desktop\Final Macro\" & Cells(X, 1) & "-OICLR.xlsx", _
                          "C:\Users\HKhan\Desktop\Final Macro\" & "OIC - Bank Details" & ".pdf", _
                          "C:\Users\HKhan\Desktop\Final Macro\" & "OICL - Bank Details" & ".pdf")

    Dim AttachedFilesCount As Long

    Dim FileLocation As Variant
    For Each FileLocation In FileLocations
        If FileExists(FileLocation) Then
            .Attachments.Add (FileLocation)
            AttachedFilesCount = AttachedFilesCount + 1
        End If
    Next FileLocation

    If AttachedFilesCount > 0 Then
        .Display 'display or send email
    Else
        .Close 'close it if no attachments
    End If

End With
```

If you now still need additional error handling on adding the attachments (personally I don't think you need it necessarily) you can implement it like this:

```
On Error Resume Next  'turn error reporting off
.Attachments.Add (FileLocation) 'the line where an error might possibly occur.
If Err.Number <> 0 Then 'throw a msgbox if there is an error
    MsgBox "Could not attach file """ & FileLocation & """ to the email." & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error " & Err.Number, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
End If
On Error Goto 0 'turn error reporting on again!
```

Comment: Peh, i cannot thank you enough for the invaluable input.

Comment: @Hasan But you can mark this answer as solution if it solved your issue.

Comment: Perhaps, we got off to a wrong start. I totally acknowledge the overuse of On Error Resume Next in my code. The requirement, actually, is that two excel files and two pdfs are to be shot in each email of mine, and to individual customers. What happens is that if a customer has just one excel record, the code would start giving me an error. To counter that, i put in the On Error Resume Next command. Thereafter, the code wouldn't stop if a client has just one excel file under his account and would run through smoothly. Reason why i never felt the need of and error handler.

Comment: my only concern now is to stop an email from being shot if the client has no excel files attached. I've tried select case, if loop, and practically cracked my head over it. But nothing seems to work

Comment: @Hasan Is there still a question now? If yes, I didn't understand, please be more specific. • If there is no question please mark the answer as solution.

Answer (score 0):

*To add condition to check if `OutMail` has Excel attachment, simply replace the following*

> ```
>        .Display
>         'send
> ```

*With these codes*

> ```
> Dim Atmt As Object
> For Each Atmt In OutMail.Attachments
>
>     Dim sFileType As String
>     sFileType = LCase$(Right$(Atmt.fileName, 4)) ' Last 4 Char in Filename
>     Debug.Print Atmt.fileName
>
>     Select Case sFileType
>         Case ".xls", "xlsx"
>
>          .Display
>         '.send
>
>     End Select
> Next
> ```