# Sending outlook email with attachments on a remainder date

Tags: excel, vba

Can any one help how to send outlook email with attachments before due date to the customer???

Comment: please read [ask]

Comment: Please do some research on Google and here on Stack Overflow. This question has been answered about 1000 times already.

Comment: I have already did a search in all the ways, if u know can u plz share the code

Comment: @Ambica B You can get going with these references. Try and put effort. If you get stuck we shall be willing to help you.(1)<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51677915/send-email-if-todays-date-is-within-four-days-of-a-due-date>

(2)<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50111843/send-only-those-emails-that-have-attachments-by-way-of-a-vba-code>

(3)<https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BiDfI4-kngw&feature=youtu.be>

Comment: @Ambica B  For attachments refer this link<https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add>

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me and will reach if i stuck anywhere :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Cell A1 is changed" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 2" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 3" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 4"

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "ron@debruin.nl"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .Body = strbody
        'You can add a file like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

See the link below for all details.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail9.htm